# How to do CSS :hover function in JSX ?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hi and thanks for the great job here. I am using react.js for my project to build my components and I feel a little bit stuck in my project right now. I am trying to style a button with a hover function and I don't know how to apply this to react.

Here is the code :

```
let button = {
    backgroundColor: colorPalette.white,
    border: "1px solid rgb(12,106,145)",
    color: colorPalette.brandCol1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    textDecoration: 'none',
    fontSize : 'inherit',
    fontWeight : 600,
    padding : "5px 8px 5px 8px"
}
```

and I would like to add a hover style to it just like we do in css with

```
button:hover {
style here.......
}
```

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: Use React and event handlers in JavaScript instead...

Comment: Could provide the actual React code?

Answer (score 27):

You can use:

```
    const styles = {
    myStyleClassName: {
            padding: '16px 0px 16px 0px',
            '& a': {
                textDecoration: 'none',
                color: '#0000ee',
            },
            '& a:hover': {
            textDecoration: 'underline',
        },
    },
    myButtonClass: {
        '&:hover': {
             textDecoration: 'underline',
        },       
    },
};
```

....

```
render() {
    <span className={myStyleClassName}><a tag><button><someDomObjct></span>
    <button className={myButtonClass}>my label</button>
}
```

See: http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested/?v=v6.0.1
The repo isn't necessary for everything, the above should work out of the box.

Comment: How would this work? First of all, should it be `<span className={styles.myStyleClassName}...`?  
And also, is it really the _className_ that should be set? Shouldn't it be the _style_ property?

Comment: I don't see how this works without jss. I am getting Object is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `onMouseEnter` `onMouseLeave` to adjust the state of the component

```
<button
  onMouseEnter={() => setButtonHovered(true)} 
  onMouseLeave={() => setButtonHovered(false)}
  className={buttonIsHovered ? 'hover' : null}
/>
```

see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) for more info

or just use a `css` class?

```
import './style.css'

<button className="Button"/>

.Button:hover {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit more to give beginners guidance on how to implement the above. For example, defining `setButtonHovered(bool)` and how/where to place the CSS for the `hover` class definition

Answer (score 7):

Using react to manage state for a hover animation is way overkill. You shouldn't need to use javascript for a simple CSS hover...You're in the browser, use the right tool for the right job, right?

So here I'll show a couple different ways to approach the same goal:

In my component I import glamor and my styles file:

```
import { style } from 'glamor';
import styles from '../styles';
```

And in my styles file, I have something like this:

```
import { style } from 'glamor';

const styles = {
redHoverbutton: style({
  backgroundColor: "#aaaaaa",
  fontSize: "1.1rem",
  transition: "all ease .5s",
  ":hover": {
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
    color: "#ffffff"
  }
})
};

export default styles;
```

And this makes the hover functionality work via css, like this:

```
<div {...styles.redHoverbutton}></div>
```

This is a css driven hover effect (with transition if you noticed) but this isn't inline css. None the less, your style can be crafted in the same file, like this:

```
let theStyle = style({ backgroundColor: "#aaaaaa",transition: "all ease .5s", ":hover": { cursor: "pointer", backgroundColor: "#ffff9b", color: "#fd0808" } });

return (<div {...theStyle}>Hover me!</div>);
```

Now, how to get the style and the spread operator onto the same line and inside of the JSX element?

```
<div {...style({ backgroundColor: "#aaaaaa", height: "30px", width: "100%", padding: "6px", fontsize: "16px", transition: "all ease .5s", ":hover": { cursor: "pointer", backgroundColor: "#ffff9b", color: "#fd0808" } })}>Hover Me!</div>
```

It may not be perfect but it works well and accomplished the same thing as a true inline style and in a similar manner.

Comment: Extremely helpful library :D glamor is awesome!